# suffix or operands invalid for `move' with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

So after trying to compile a C program with gcc on Mac I was met with an unexpected error.

The original program was reduced to a simple test printf statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
printf("test");
return 0;
}
```

error:

```
/var/folders/bh/npq9sw994k3bzrxgwyc9kv2h0000gn/T//cceggs5M.s:36:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/bh/npq9sw994k3bzrxgwyc9kv2h0000gn/T//cceggs5M.s:44:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/bh/npq9sw994k3bzrxgwyc9kv2h0000gn/T//cceggs5M.s:52:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/bh/npq9sw994k3bzrxgwyc9kv2h0000gn/T//cceggs5M.s:57:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
```

What causes this issue and how do i resolve it?

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: sorry @ThisaruGuruge the c code is irrelevant a simple c file with a printf statement  and ' gcc filename.c -o test ' would produce the same errors. ''cceggs5M.s' changes everytime the command was run.

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge which code would you expect me to post in this case?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems to be a conflict between brew and Macports. I dont know specifically what caused the conflict.

But [Uninstalling Macports](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) allowed me to successfully compile without the issue:

```
sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

Hope this helps anyone else experiencing the same issue.